assigning the coordinate system to my las catalog and my code doesn't work
I have a LAS catalog data that doesn't have any coordinate system. Without a coordinate system I can easily compute pixel metrics, but when I assign the coordinate it doesn't work; i need to have x and y for the outcome table. Can you help me with the problem?
normalized1987<-readLAScatalog("normalized1987")
st_crs(normalized1987)<-4326
heigh<-pixel_metrics(normalized1987,func = .stdmetrics_z,res = 30)

I tried LAS check and I got this error:
Checking overlapping tiles...Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
      Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 crosses edge 2
     In addition: Warning messages:
     1: In st_is_longlat(x) :
      bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
      2: In st_is_longlat(x) :
       bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data

but also filter duplicate doesn't work.

EPSG:4326 is a longitude/latitude CRS. Your point cloud is in a projected CRS. The error comes from the terra package when trying to build a raster in long/lat with invalid projected coordinated
